# Derivative of sum of Schwartz functions

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, schwartz-space

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a Schwartz-class function.

Let $F(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}f(x-2\pi n)$. I understand that because Schwartz-class functions are nice, this series converges absolutely and uniformly for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

However, why is $F$ differentiable, and why is its derivative equal to $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}f'(x-2\pi n)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 
$$f(x+h-2\pi n)-f(x-2\pi n)=\int_0^hf'(s+x-2\pi n)\mathrm ds=hf'(h+x-2\pi n)-\int_0^h sf''(s+x-\pi n)\mathrm ds,$$
and since $f$ and its derivatives are Schwartz functions, we can take the sum $n\in\mathbb Z$. Indeed, if $g$ is a Schwartz function, then $|g(x-2\pi n)|\leqslant \frac C{(1+|x-2\pi n|)^2}$ hence for $K$ compact and $n$ such that $\operatorname{diam}(K)\lt 2n\pi$, $\sup_{x\in K}|g(x-2\pi n)|\leqslant{C'}{n^2}$.

This gives 
$$\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}h=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}f'(x+h-2\pi n)-\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\frac 1h\int_0^hsf''(s+x-\pi n)\mathrm ds.$$
The convergence of the first series is uniform on compact sets. For the second one, we use the substitution $s=th$ to get the wanted result.

Comment: I've edited. Is it clearer?

Comment: I integrated by parts.

Comment: It appears in the first displayed equation at the end of the first line, and not on the second one since I divided by $h$.

Comment: I'm quite sure there should be no $h$ at the end of the first line. Could you check your integration by parts again?

Comment: I checked, and you are right.

Comment: Thanks. Now, I agree with your last displayed equation. However, I don't see why this gives the desired result. Could you please add more detail too? (Sorry, won't bother you much longer :) )